# How to limit the output of a Ruby `pp` call?

Tags: ruby

I've got a recursive object (Cucumber::Rails::World.scenario) which I'd like to inspect (in order to find the tags belonging to the current scenario). `scenario.inspect` never finishes, and `pp scenario` prints so fast that even with a quick series of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> it fills about three thousand lines. How can I limit the output?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pretty_inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pp/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-pretty_inspect) to get it as a string, then get only the first n characters:

```
pp_output = scenario.pretty_inspect; nil
puts pp_output[0..n]; nil
```

Note the trailing `nil`s cause IRb to display the return value `nil` rather than the entire object, which cleans up output substantially.

For even more flexibility, save it to a file:

```
File.open "pp-output.txt", "w" do |f|
  f.puts scenario.pretty_inspect
end
```

Then view in the pager of your choice:

```
$ less pp-output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert `gets` at certain points (in between small chunks of `pp`). Then, you can go through them slowly by inputting enter after each chunk.